# Tool for Azure service resource analyzment BEFORE deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops

If I create an Azure cloud services (implemented using .NET Core in my case), is there a way to get an estimation of the resources needed for the service BEFORE (not analyzing it after the fact) it is deployed to the cluster? By resources I mean number of cpus needed, memory being used etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before deployment any application We can use [Azure pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/calculator/)  to analysis our uses and cost as per our requirement .

And alternatively based on the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-manage-costs#review-estimated-costs-in-the-azure-portal) we can review estimated costs according to our requirement tool in the Azure portal:

> When you create an App Service app or an App Service plan, you can see
> the estimated costs.
>
> To create an app and view the estimated price:
>
> 1. On the create page, scroll down to  **App Service plan**, and click  **Create new**.
> 2. Specify a name and click  **OK**.
> 3. Next to  **Sku and size**, click  **Change size**.
> 4. Review the estimated price shown in the summary. The following screenshot is an example and doesn't reflect current pricing.

[image: Review estimated cost for each pricing tier in the portal]

For more information you can refer this MS DOC:  [Sizes for Cloud Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-sizes-specs)